# New index is empty

Tags: google-app-engine, build, indexing, populate

I've created a new index using the index.yaml file, and once it ready with the "Serving" status it still empty, and when using it i get no data.

this is the second index that did the same thing, with the first i updated all entities to re-populate it and then it worked and gave data back.

also, when i look in the admin page, the Index "Entry Count" and "Index Storage" are empty for the new index.

is this the expected behavior or am i doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you rewritten the entities you want in the index? If your new index is serving for kind "MyModel", you need to do a write op, e.g. `put()`, for all MyModel entities. Indexing happens only during write ops.

Comment: @Ani this is only for automatic field indexes. Composite indexes set in `index.yaml` rebuild themselves.

Comment: @Oded - what properties does your index in `index.yaml` have?

Comment: @peter thanks. This also what I know from the doc. My properties are only integer and strings.

Comment: could it be that this happen because that the updated index.yaml was upload to a new application version and not the current? @PeterKnego my index includes __key__, 6 different integer properties and one string

Comment: Hi, anyone have any idea on this issue? any help will be very much appreciated..